# How to know in Accurev that element is modified on other streams

Tags: accurev

I can use `accurev wip` command to find the element changed in other workspaces.

How can I know in Accurev CLI (or GUI) that the element is modified on other streams, not workspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a script to obtain this info.

Basically you will run the command:

accurev show -p  -fxg -s "Stream Name" -R streams

You will parse this list looking for "hasDefaultGroup="true"".

For each stream that matches, execute the 'accurev stat -d -s' command.